# when i run flutter upgrade command my gradle is not working properly

Tags: flutter, dart

I have run `flutter upgrade` command it take too much time and after that I am runing my project that was working perfectly before upgrade but now gradle build error is shown on screen here is the console detail.

```
Checking Dart SDK version...
Flutter requires PowerShell 5.0 or newer.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows for more.
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Running "flutter pub get" in gtvsports1...                          4.0s
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G920W8 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Checking Dart SDK version...
Flutter requires PowerShell 5.0 or newer.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows for more.
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Running "flutter pub get" in gtvsports1...                          1.1s
W
rong full snapshot version, expected '1d7acad1540192ac459cf60344efb
7c1' found '4d75e7eb64b77034b9e3e19577811de7'

I
solate creation failed

Compiler failed on C:\Users\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\gtvsports1\lib\main.dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 747

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebugArm64'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 28s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: for `"Wrong full snapshot version"` i would try to run `flutter clean` first...

Comment: it did not work for me.

Comment: still `"Wrong full snapshot version"` message?

Comment: yes same error shown